# What connection string is SSIS using

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an old SSIS package built under 2008R2.  Other devs have tweaked it over the years.  When I open it and manipulate it I have an issue where it WILL NOT persist the password in the connection manager.  Otherwise I can more or less edit it.

When I save the package and deploy just the dtsx file to a test server, it is using a connection to a different server.  I've opened up the raw XML and find no references to that server.  The only connection in the package points to the server it is supposed to use.

How do I figure out where it is pulling this phantom connection string from?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely its stored as part of a [package configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141682.aspx) which has many possible sources from a SQL or a separate XML config file.  Check the command line options for a configuration option where you are executing the package to determine the source. Package configurations override the default values of parameters used in a package, and abstract environment specific values (conn strs, file paths, credentials,...) for easier testing/QA, without hard coding values.

Comment: Thanks.  Cannot seem to find a way to get where the current config is.  I see the /Conf allows me to set one.

Comment: How is the package being run?  Is it thru a SQL Agent job, an SSIS Server, or via command line?  How it is run will provide more insight to where to look